# Tor browser issue even though time is synchronized

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

8/19/2018 20:53:30 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/19/2018 20:53:30 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/19/2018 20:53:30 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/19/2018 20:53:30 PM.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/19/2018 20:53:31 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 3E53D3979DB07EFD736661C934A1DED14127B684 at 217.79.179.177:9001) 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.800 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.800 [WARN]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/19/2018 20:54:39 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/19/2018 20:54:40 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem by my self. hope it must be useful to others

tried uninstalling the antivirus
tried uninstalling the TOR browser...
tried to synchronize the clock..

but the real problem was

there was an software called
"search awesome" installed in the machine
uninstalled and TOR started working..